# How to extend the Django's static template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

Django's built in `{% static %}` tag automatically prepends the path to my s3 static assets . I however need to alter the path with more information before retrieving the files. Is it possible to extend the built in 'static' template tag to do this?

I am aware that I can create my own template tag and simply replace the static tag however I am working with a large code base and doing this would be very time consuming.

Comment: Can you reveal the reason for extending it? Any details about "altering the path". But yes, you can replace it with your own tag which is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) and you can read the source code of [django's static tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/76c0b32f826469320c59709d31e2f2126dd7c505/django/templatetags/static.py#L162-L167) and extend it or create your own.